# How to keep score for player and computer?

Tags: python

This is a rock,paper,scissors game.

```
import random

options = ("rock", "paper", "scissors")  # three options
running = True
score = 0
while running:  # continuing the game

    player = ""  # storing the player's choices
    computer = random.choice(options)  # computer will choose a random choice from the options

    while player not in options:  # the player has to choose one of the options, if not, it will still keep on looping
        player = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")

    print("Player: " + player)  # player(user) vs. computer
    print("Computer: " + computer)

    if player == computer:
       score = 0
        print("It's a tie!")
    elif player == "rock" and computer == "scissors":
        score += 1
        print("You win!")
    elif player == "paper" and computer == "rock":
        score += 1
        print("You win!")
    elif player == "scissors" and computer == "paper":
        score += 1
        print("You win!")
    else:
        score += 1
        print("You lose!")
        print(score, "for computer")

    print(score)


    play_again = input("Play again? (y/n): ").lower()
    if play_again == "y":
        running = True
        print("Yes sir!")
    else:
        running = False
        print("Thanks for playing! ")
```

My goal was trying to keep score for player and computer. If the user wins, they get a point. If the computer wins, they get a point. If its a tie, neither of them gets a point.

Comment: `if player == computer: score = 0` has the effect of reseting the score, but you say you want neither to get a point. These are different things. And since each player probably needs their own score, you will need to use something other than a single number to keep track of the score. Maybe a dict or tuple? Alternatively the a single number could be the player's score and you could subtract from it when the computer wins. This would mean negative scores are possible if you are unlucky.

Comment: Instead of a single `score` variable, make two variables: one for the player score and one for the computer score.  When the player wins, add 1 to the player score, and when the computer wins, add 1 to the computer score.

Comment: Just remove the line `score = 0` under `if player == computer:`. As Mark above says, you are resetting the score to zero if its a tie. While you are at it, you need to set `score -= 1` in your else statement otherwise score always increases regardless of who wins.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows you three rounds of three games of a simulated user input game with its result. It is your code only slightly changed to count properly the results:

```
import random

lst_user_input = [
"list faking user input:"
,"scissors"
,"paper"
,"rock"
,"y"
,"scissors"
,"paper"
,"rock"
,"y"
,"scissors"
,"paper"
,"rock"
,"n"
]
options = ("rock", "paper", "scissors")  # three options
running = True
computer_score = 0
player_score   = 0
round_no       = 0
while running:  # continuing the game
 
    #player = ""  # storing the player's choices
    round_no += 1
    computer = random.choice(options)  # computer will choose a random choice from the options

    #while player not in options:  # the player has to choose one of the options, if not, it will still keep on looping
    #    player = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")
    print(round_no)
    player = lst_user_input[round_no]
    print("Player  : " + player)  # player(user) vs. computer
    print("Computer: " + computer)

    if player == computer:
        print("It's a tie!")
    elif player == "rock" and computer == "scissors":
        player_score += 1
        print("You win!")
    elif player == "paper" and computer == "rock":
        player_score += 1
        print("You win!")
    elif player == "scissors" and computer == "paper":
        player_score += 1
        print("You win!")
    else:
        computer_score += 1
        print("You lose!")

    print("Player   score:", player_score)
    print("Computer score:", computer_score)

    if not round_no % 3: # ask only each 3 rounds 
        #play_again = input("Play next 3-rounds? (y/n): ").lower()
        round_no +=1
        play_again = lst_user_input[round_no]
        if play_again == "y":
            running = True
            print("Yes sir!")
        else:
            running = False
            print("Thanks for playing! ")
```

Here an example of printed output:

```
1
Player  : scissors
Computer: paper
You win!
Player   score: 1
Computer score: 0
2
Player  : paper
Computer: scissors
You lose!
Player   score: 1
Computer score: 1
3
Player  : rock
Computer: paper
You lose!
Player   score: 1
Computer score: 2
Yes sir!
5
Player  : scissors
Computer: paper
You win!
Player   score: 2
Computer score: 2
6
Player  : paper
Computer: rock
You win!
Player   score: 3
Computer score: 2
Thanks for playing!
```